# How to get dragged column definition in ag grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Question :
How to find out which column is being dragged when user drags the the column.

I have tried using ondragstarted on gridoptions but it does not give which column is being dragged?

**goal:**
I need to perform few operations, if user drags and drops column outside grid on specific div inside dom.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to bind to the [`columnMoved`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#columns) event that contains details of the column that's dragged. Try the following

Template

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
  #agGrid 
  (columnMoved)="onChange($event)"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Controller

```js
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.columns[0].colId);                 // <-- column ID
  console.log(event.columns[0].colDef.headerName);     // <-- column header name
  console.log(event.columns[0].colDef.field);          // <-- column field
}
```

Comment: columnMoved only gives moved column only if you move inside grid area. It does not give details if column is being dragged outside grid. I need to perform few opearations if user drags and drops column outside grid on specific area.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using (columnVisible) along with a check source = "uiColumnDragged".

```
onColumnVisible(e) {
if(e.source === "uiColumnDragged") {
//Add your logic
}
}
```